# Connect MySQL database from other server in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, connection

My code is similar to below:

```
    $hostname = '192.xxx.xxx.xx';
    $database = 'test_db';
    $username = 'test_user';
    $password = 'test_pw';
```

.... more code.
I got Error Message:

```
    mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'test_user'@'xxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxx.com' (using password: YES)
```

I have also add Remote MySQL > access host [192.xxx.xxx.xx] in site server
And also same in database server (but of site ip/host)

Comment: It would help to show the line that does the connection as well, not just some variables that might not even be used, or used correctly.

Comment: Have you confirmed these credentials are valid with a tool like the `mysql` command-line tool or MySQL Workbench?

Comment: You must create the user `'test_user'@'xxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxx.com'` (or the user with pattern host part) with proper password and permissions.